# Android: onClick on LinearLayout with TextView and Button

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick, android-xml

I have a Fragment that uses the following XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/card"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="editActions"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/CardTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="@string/title_workstation" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/factory_button_edit"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="@string/label_edit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, I have an **onClick** parameter set on `LinearLayout`. Now on the `TextView` this one is triggered correctly, and on all empty area. Just on the `Button` it doesn't invoke the onClick method that I set.

Is this normal? What do I have to do so that the onClick method is invoked everywhere on the `LinearLayout`?

Comment: try to remove this properties android:clickable="true" from LinearLayout.

Comment: Doesn't change anything. All I had to do was to set `android:clickable="false"` on the button, or like in the solution `android:onClick="editActions"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add onClick Action for your button dirrectly in code 
 like this:

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.factory_button_edit);
btn.setOnClickListener(button_click);

      OnClickListener button_click = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            editActions;
        }
    };
```

or xml add

```
android:onClick="editActions"
```

to your button

Comment: I solved it by adding `android:clickable="false"` to my button. But your solution has the same result, so I'm accepting it as the right answer.

Comment: @Terry, your answer is better, since the button actually 'steals' the event from it's father layout, so it's more appropriate to set its clickable attr to false.

Answer (score 12):

This is what you need in your LinearLayout :

```
android:onClick="editActions" 
android:clickable="true"
```

and also in your class which call that xml some method:

```
public void editActions(View view){

           //something TODO

    }
```

Comment: Got a   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException  with this method. ??

Answer (score 5):

To make your layout clickable with its children you need add this option for every ***child***:

```
 android:clickable="false"
```

Then click handling will go ***up*** to ***parent***.

Comment: This is still the correct answer IMO.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use a [TouchDelegate](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate):

> Android provides the TouchDelegate class to make it possible for a
>   parent to extend the touchable area of a child view beyond the child's
>   bounds. This is useful when the child has to be small, but should have
>   a larger touch region. You can also use this approach to shrink the
>   child's touch region if need be.

Comment: Upvote for an interesting way. Yet a bit too much for my simple layout.

Answer (score 2):

try to do that

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/card"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="editActions"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/CardTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_workstation" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/factory_button_edit"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="clickMe"
        android:text="@string/label_edit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and on your Activity or fragement

```
    public void editActions(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Layout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void clickMe(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "clickMe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I did. Doesn't change anything.

Comment: What happens is that clickMe is called on the button, and editActions everywhere else. But I want the LinearLayout onClick method (editActions) overriding the child's behavior. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you want override child's behaviour, like what?? button click ??

Comment: I want that the parent LinearLayout is clickable, and calls editActions onclick, anywhere you touch. If the button is touched, the same should happen, but the button does not need to be activated (look "clicked").

Comment: than it's sample, call the same methode on  button click listener

Answer (score 2):

Well, if this a bar with some children and you want to have only this bar clickable with children area - try add this option for every child in parent:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

and of course add `setOnClickListener` for main layout, example on [my blog](http://androidstudio2.blogspot.com/2014/04/android-make-layout-clickable-with-its.html)

Example:

```
<LinearLayout  
      android:id="@+id/parent"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"  
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
      android:orientation="horizontal">  
      <ImageButton  
           android:clickable="false"  
           android:layout_width="40dp"  
           android:layout_height="40dp"  
           android:text="Cinema"  
           android:textSize="13sp"  
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />  
      <Button  
           android:clickable="false"  
           android:layout_width="match_parent"  
           android:layout_height="40dp"  
           android:text="Check in"  
           android:textSize="13sp"/>  
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should remove this parameter for your Button:

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

Comment: I did. Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
View.OnClickListener myViewHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                RelativeLayout pressedRelViewx = (RelativeLayout) v;
                TextView pressedTextView = (TextView) pressedRelViewx.getChildAt(0);
                String text = pressedTextView.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "My Text "+ text , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;
        }
    };


Relative_Layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.my_container);
Relative_Layout.setOnClickListener(myViewHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok this may be late , but it will help have others, who are looking for

> how to set onClick Listener for layouts [android].

```
LinearLayout mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.your_linear_layout_name);

mLinearLayout.setonClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
   @Overide
   public void onClick(View v){
     //do want to do here

    }

});
```

Note:

> you can not perform onClick Listener on button when button is inside
>   the linear layout which is already listening to onClick , and if do
>   that first parent(Linear Layout) is get clicked.
>   It is best practice to do not preform nested onClick Listeners.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate copy-paste code, you can set a `OnClickListener` to all of the chidlren `View`'s with code:

```
private void setClickListenerRecursively(View view, View.OnClickListener listener){
    view.setOnClickListener(listener);

    if(view instanceof ViewGroup){
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;
        for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
            View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
            setClickListenerRecursively(child, listener);
        }
    }
}
```